# Mock function not being called in Jest + Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I have written a test that mocks the sumbitChoice() function as this function is responsible for an API call. The function is called on clicking the button, '#buttonOption1'.

Currently, the test's assertion fails i.e. 'Expected mock function to have been called.'

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { waitForState } from 'enzyme-async-helpers';

describe('App', () => {

 it('should call the submitChoice method on click' , () => {

  //arrange
    const mockSubmitChoice = jest.fn();
    const app = mount(<App submitChoice={ mockSubmitChoice } />);

  //act
    app.find('#buttonOption1').simulate('click');

  //assert
    expect(mockSubmitChoice).toBeCalled();

  })

})
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state =  { imageURLs:  [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/comparison')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(images => this.setState({
         imageURLs: [...this.state.imageURLs, images]
      }))
      // .bind(this);
      console.log(this.state)
  }

  submitChoice(data) {
    fetch('/comparison', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify([...this.state.imageURLs, data]),
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <img id='firstImage' className='image' src={this.state.imageURLs[0]} />
        <img id='secondImage' className='image' src={this.state.imageURLs[1]} />
        <button id='buttonOption1' className='button' onClick={this.submitChoice(this.state.imageURLs[0])}>Select Option 1</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I went for a different test method in the end. This passes:

```
  it('should call the submitChoice method on click', () => {

    //arrange
    const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, 'submitChoice'); 
    const app = shallow(<App />);

    //act
    const button = app.find('#buttonOption1')
    button.simulate('click');

    //assert
    expect(spy).toBeCalled();

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your `this.submitChoice()` function in the constructor.

```
this.submitChoice = this.submitChoice.bind(this)
```

Comment: ^Though this improves the production code, the test still fails in the same way.

Comment: @Oliver How are you calling the function after implementing what I wrote above?

Also, you need to mock up some data to pass to the function for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding your function to onClick event, you are calling it and since it return nothing you are basically binding undefined to onclick.

this:

```
onClick={this.submitChoice(this.state.imageURLs[0])}
```

is same as this:

```
onClick-{undefined}
```

because

```
console.log(this.submitChoice(this.state.imageURLs[0])) // output will be undefined
```

so just change your code like this:

```
 onClick={this.submitChoice}
```

and find another way to pass data, since you are just passing static dammy data it should not be much issue anyway.